# Center GridPane Square in ScrollPane Viewport

Tags: java, javafx, centering, scrollpane, gridpane

I have a 20x20 `GridPane` of uniformly sized squares which is representing data from a two-dimensional array of the same size, placed in a `ScrollPane` such that one can use it to pan around.  The width and height in pixels of the `GridPane` are both much greater than the respective dimensions of the `ScrollPane`.

My problem is that I have been unable to make a functional method that centers the viewport of the `ScrollPane`on the `GridPane` square located at a set of designated coordinates.

My understanding of the `scrollPane.setHvalue(double)` and `scrollPane.setVvalue(double)`which I have been attempting to utilize is that the double value passed into them is the percentage of the axis that it sets the scroll to.  However, when I write the code assuming that, it fails to center the view on the intended square, sometimes with the square not even being anywhere on the viewport:

```
private void centerViewOn(double x, double y){
    scrollPane.setHvalue(x/grid.getDimensionX());
    scrollPane.setVvalue(y/grid.getDimensionY());
}
```

Where `grid` is an instance of a class whose only relevance to this question is that it has the dimensions of the grid, and `double x` and `double y` are the x,y coordinates in the GridPane of the square that is intended to be centered.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix this?

EDIT:
In accordance with James_D's suggestion, I'm including what I made as a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example:

```
private ScrollPane scrollPane;
private GridPane gridPane;
private double dimensionX;
private double dimensionY;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
    gridPane   = new GridPane();
    dimensionX = 20;
    dimensionY = 20;

    Pane temp;
    for(int x = 0; x < dimensionX; ++x){
        for(int y = 0; y < dimensionY; ++y){
            temp = new Pane();
            temp.setPrefSize(100, 100);
            temp.setOnMouseClicked( e -> {
                centerViewOn(GridPane.getColumnIndex((Pane)e.getSource()), GridPane.getRowIndex((Pane)e.getSource()));
                ((Pane)e.getSource()).setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue");
            });
            gridPane.add(temp, x, y);
        }
    }

    gridPane.setGridLinesVisible(true);
    scrollPane.setContent(gridPane);

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(scrollPane));
    primaryStage.show();
}

private void centerViewOn(double x, double y){
    double viewportWidth    = scrollPane.getViewportBounds().getWidth();
    double maxHscrollPixels = gridPane.getWidth() - viewportWidth;
    double hscrollPixels    = viewportWidth / 2 - (x + 0.5) * dimensionX / 20;
    scrollPane.setHvalue(hscrollPixels / maxHscrollPixels);

    double viewportHeight   = scrollPane.getViewportBounds().getHeight();
    double maxVscrollPixels = gridPane.getHeight() - viewportHeight;
    double vscrollPixels    = viewportHeight / 2 - (y + 0.5) * dimensionY / 20;
    scrollPane.setVvalue(vscrollPixels / maxVscrollPixels);
}
```

Comment: So, you want the `ScrollPane` to center the view on the `grid` when they stop scrolling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scroll pane's horizontal scroll values vary between `scrollPane.getHmin()` and `scrollPane.getHmax()`. Those are in arbitrary units, with the amount scrolled in pixels being linearly interpolated across the range.

The possible horizontal scroll amount in pixels ranges from zero to (grid pane width - scrollpane viewport width).

So you have

```
(hvalue - hmin) / (hmax - hmin) = scrollPixels / (gridPaneWidth - viewportWidth)
```

and so after some algebra you get

```
hvalue = hmin + (hmax - hmin) * scrollPixels / (gridPaneWidth - viewportWidth)
```

Assuming each column is the same width, and there are `dimensionX` columns, `x` columns will have total width `x * gridPaneWidth / dimensionX` pixels. Since you want to scroll to the center of the cell, add another half cell, and since you want the center of the cell to be in the center of the viewport, subtract `viewportWidth / 2`. So you have:

```
hscrollPixels =  (x + 0.5) * gridPane.getWidth() / dimensionX - viewportWidth / 2
```

Scrolling vertically is exactly analogous.

The default values for `hmin` and `hmax` are `0` and `1`, respectively, so you can simplify things a bit if you assume these don't change.

So I think you end up with

```
private void centerViewOn(double x, double y){
    double viewportWidth    = scrollPane.getViewportBounds().getWidth();
    double maxHscrollPixels = gridPane.getWidth() - viewportWidth;
    double hscrollPixels    =  (x + 0.5) * gridPane.getWidth() / dimensionX - viewportWidth / 2;
    scrollPane.setHvalue(hscrollPixels / maxHscrollPixels);

    double viewportHeight   = scrollPane.getViewportBounds().getHeight();
    double maxVscrollPixels = gridPane.getHeight() - viewportHeight;
    double vscrollPixels    =  (y + 0.5) * gridPane.getHeight() / dimensionY - viewportHeight / 2;
    scrollPane.setVvalue(vscrollPixels / maxVscrollPixels);
}
```

Note that not all cells can be scrolled to the center: if they are too close to the edges, they will be scrolled as close as possible to the center, but the scroll pane will not allow blank space (unless the content is smaller than the viewport).

Here's the complete example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ScrollToCenter extends Application {

    private ScrollPane scrollPane;
    private GridPane gridPane;
    private double dimensionX;
    private double dimensionY;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
        gridPane   = new GridPane();
        dimensionX = 20;
        dimensionY = 20;

        for(int x = 0; x < dimensionX; ++x){
            for(int y = 0; y < dimensionY; ++y){
                Pane temp = new Pane();
                temp.setPrefSize(100, 100);
                temp.setOnMouseClicked( e -> {
                    centerViewOn(GridPane.getColumnIndex(temp), GridPane.getRowIndex(temp));
                    temp.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue");
                });
                gridPane.add(temp, x, y);
            }
        }

        gridPane.setGridLinesVisible(true);
        scrollPane.setContent(gridPane);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(scrollPane));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void centerViewOn(double x, double y){
        double viewportWidth    = scrollPane.getViewportBounds().getWidth();
        double maxHscrollPixels = gridPane.getWidth() - viewportWidth;
        double hscrollPixels    =  (x + 0.5) * gridPane.getWidth() / dimensionX - viewportWidth / 2;
        scrollPane.setHvalue(hscrollPixels / maxHscrollPixels);

        double viewportHeight   = scrollPane.getViewportBounds().getHeight();
        double maxVscrollPixels = gridPane.getHeight() - viewportHeight;
        double vscrollPixels    =  (y + 0.5) * gridPane.getHeight() / dimensionY - viewportHeight / 2;
        scrollPane.setVvalue(vscrollPixels / maxVscrollPixels);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: While this was helpful, it ultimately did not quite work.  I think this is because I did a poor job of explaining `grid.getDimensionX()`.  To clarify, that method returns the number of columns in the grid, which is 20 in this example.  (it's a method rather than a hardcoded number because I will eventually be implementing the ability to resize the grid, so I'm looking for a solution that works for a grid of any number of rows and columns)

Comment: @narf0708 Probably your best bet is to create a [MCVE] and edit your question to include it.

Comment: I am leaving `hmin` and `hmax` at their defaults, so if I'm reading properly, that last line should simplify to `scrollPane.setHvalue(hscrollPixels / maxHscrollPixels);`
Also, I must admit I'm a bit confused at where some of your numbers are coming from.  What's the purpose of the 2 and the 0.5 in `viewportWidth / 2 - (x + 0.5)` ?

Comment: `viewportWidth / 2` gives you the middle of the viewport... `(x+0.5)` because you need to center the cell, not scroll the edge of the cell to the center. (But I may have the whole thing backwards there; again, if you post a complete example it would help.)

Comment: Added a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.  Hope this helps.

Comment: @narf0708 Yes, it helped. I had the scroll amount reversed and had also misinterpreted `dimensionX/Y`. Updated the answer and added a little more explanation.